# I would like to loop over a specific combination of 2 variables. How can I achieve this?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I would like to have a for loop over 2 variables, but ideally I would like to have it as follows

1. (1,1)
2. (2,1) (2,2) (1,2)
3. (3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (2,3) (1,3)
4. (4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (3,4) (2,4) (1,4)
5. etc.

If I'm looking correctly this should cover all combinations. How can I achieve this hierarchy with one or two for loops? The order in each "level" doesn't matter.

My solution was:

```
for i=1:4
    for j = 1:i
        [i j] 
        [j i] 
    end 
end.
```

This gives the desired values, but repeats (i,i) values. The problem with this is that it only works for square matrices, and sadly this isn't always the case for me.

Comment: Show us some code of what you've tried. This is pretty basic for any programming language, prove that you've made some effort

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that. My solution was: for i=1:4, for j = 1:i, [i j] and [j i] end end. This gives the desired values, but repeats (i,i) values. Works but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

so if you want a for loop to produce these pair of values, here's a way to do that :

```
b=[];
for n=1:3
    for k=1:n
        a(:,k)=[n k];
    end
    b{n}= [a flipud(a(:,1:size(a,2)-1))]';
end


celldisp(b)

b{1} =

 1     1



b{2} =

 2     1
 2     2
 1     2



b{3} =

 3     1
 3     2
 3     3
 1     3
 2     3
```

you can select the cell you want in b to get the pairs of values needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
[x, y] = meshgrid([1:1:5],6:1:10);
foo = @(x_, y_) sprintf("C(%d, %d)\n", x_, y_);
foo(x, y)
```

This is sub-optimal as it computes (n,n) twice.

[matlab meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the input. For me the best implementation was the following, where n and m are the range of i and j:

```
for k = 2:n+m
    [X,Y] = find((([1:n]' + [1:m])==k));
    for I= [X Y]'
        i = I(1)
        j = I(2)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Define array with the elements as needed in the outut
A = 1:4;

%// Get mask of valid elements according to specified hierarchy
mask = bsxfun(@eq,bsxfun(@max,A,A.'),permute(A,[3 1 2])); %//'

%// Get indics of valid positions
[X,Y,Z] = ind2sub(size(mask),find(mask));

%// Finally segregate elements for each hierarchy
XY = [X,Y];
out = arrayfun(@(n) XY(Z==n,:),1:4,'Uni',0);
```

Sample run -

1) Input:

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3     4
```

2) Mask:

```
>> mask
mask(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
mask(:,:,2) =
     0     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
mask(:,:,3) =
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0
     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0
mask(:,:,4) =
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1
```

3) Output:

```
>> celldisp(out)
out{1} =
     1     1
out{2} =
     2     1
     1     2
     2     2
out{3} =
     3     1
     3     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3
out{4} =
     4     1
     4     2
     4     3
     1     4
     2     4
     3     4
     4     4
```